# Moving multi-boot HDD between laptops: Linux works, Windows 7 does not

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, boot, multi-boot

I had a laptop that is now dead, it had a double-boot configuration, Linux&Win7.

I quickly needed access to its files and moved the hard drive on a different laptop. All seemed fine, the boot menu appears, selecting my Linux system (which is the main one) it works as before, but when I select Windows 7, it starts booting, the Windows 7 desktop interface appears where it says "welcome" and the name of the system, but after that it goes to the black screen saying boot error.

What could be the cause and how to diagnoze this further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booting in safe mode in Windows 7, the session was initiated, desktop became accessible, and the system started looking for some drivers mentioning some incompatibilities, but also saying that reboot is needed. If I waited longer the system would crush with some blue screen of death; but when restart was executed soon enough, then the system booted without problem. At which point drivers could be installed, and then normal operation restored.

Linux includes more if not all drivers for different laptops, while Windows needed something more or some resetting when the system was moved with the HDD on a different machine with different components.

Answer (score 0):

**My thoughts**

Windows 7 is not inherently portable although I've personally had mixed results with that. Sometimes it works pretty good. It seems like during the initial install of windows 7 it discards certain drivers that don't apply to the computer it's installing on. It's not just going to copy all the unnecessary drivers from the install DVD. It's only grabbing the ones that apply to the computer it's being installed on.

**Possible Solution**

Here are some things you could try but I'm not sure if it will work.

1. Grab a windows 7 iso. Put it on a dvd. Use the built in recovery tools. Cross your fingers and hope it doesn't mess up your dualboot.
2. You have to reinstall windows 7 and redo your dualboot configuration from scratch.

Comment: It seems you are right about the drivers. See my own answer on the details of how this was fixed rather easy.